cin.ignore borra la primera letra del nombre ingresado por getline
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Nomina {
public:
  // atributos
  std::string nombre;
  int horas_trabajadas;
  int valor_hora;

  // constructores
  Nomina() : nombre(""), 
horas_trabajadas(0), valor_hora(0) {}

  Nomina(const std::string &n, int h_t, int v_h)
  : nombre(n), horas_trabajadas(h_t), valor_hora(v_h) {}

  // métodos

  void ingresar_datos() {
std::cout << "Ingrese el nombre del empleado:" << std::endl;
std::cin.ignore();
getline(std::cin, nombre);
std::cout << "\nIngrese la cantidad de horas trabajadas:\n";
std::cin >> horas_trabajadas;
std::cout << "\nIngrese el valor de la hora trabajada:\n";
std::cin >> valor_hora;
  }

  void mostrar_pago() const {
std::cout << "Nombre: " << nombre
          << "\nHoras trabajadas: " << horas_trabajadas
          << "\nValor hora: $" << valor_hora << "\nValor pagado: $"
          << horas_trabajadas * valor_hora << std::endl;
          std::cout << "===================\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  char continuar;
  std::vector<Nomina> empleados;
  Nomina nomina;
  do{
    nomina.ingresar_datos();
    empleados.push_back(nomina);
    std::cout << "Continuar: s/n\n";
    std::cin >> continuar;
    while(continuar != 'n' && continuar != 'N' && continuar != 's' && continuar != 'S'){
  std::cout << "Ingrese una respuesta válida: \n";
   std::cin >> continuar;
}
if(continuar == 'n' || continuar == 'N'){
  std::cout << "Sesión terminada\n";
}
  } while(continuar != 'n' && continuar != 'N');
  for(auto it = empleados.begin(); it != empleados.end(); ++it){
it->mostrar_pago();
  }
   return 0; 
}

Desaparece la primera letra del nombre del primer empleado guardado en el vector ej: ernando, arolina, pero solo del primero, los nombres de los demás empleados salen completos

Eso pasa porque cin.ignore solo deberia aplicarse después de que existan caracteres a ignorar. En la primera llamada a la función el usuario no a ingresado nada por stdin previamente  siquiera, dado que el parámetro count de cin.ignore es 1 por defecto, perderás un  carácter de la entrada. En las siguientes llamadas si que existirán espacios en blanco dejados por std::cin >> ... previamente, por lo que ésto no ocurre.

No hay mucho que explicar, cin.ignore() siempre va a consumir un caracter (o la cantidad que pases como parámetro).
Entiendo que lo usas por el getline, pero no deberías usarlo si no hay nada que debas ignorar.
Sugiero que utilices scanf(" ") para descartar espacio en blanco (y saltos de línea). O si prefieres seguir con cin.ignore, usa cin.peek() para saber si el caracter siguiente es un salto de línea o no.
if (cin.peek() == '\n') cin.ignore();

Si quieres entender mejor por qué y cuándo sucede el problema de los saltos de línea, puedes ver esta pregunta.
